# In a GitPitch presentation, how can I increase the font size of a code block?

Tags: reveal.js, gitpitch

I am creating a code slide using GitPitch: https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/wiki/Code-Slides

For my code slides, I would like the text to be as large as possible.

I see that the GitPitch service makes use of Reveal.js.
https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/wiki/Slideshow-Custom-CSS

In Reveal.js CSS classes, is there a recommended way to stretch/expand/enlarge the font of a code sample?

Answer (score 3):

The following CSS seems to work well in full-screen mode.

```
.reveal pre code {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.reveal pre {
  width: 120%;
  margin-left: -10%;
}
```